# IQOoption bot API GUI, how I create an GUI with Python for a tradingbot?

Tags: binary, trading, binaries, iq

I can't integrate my tab made in qtdesigner to log in to the brokerage, does anyone have experience with this?
I have all the negotiation parts, just the GUI I have problems...

I searched all over the internet for courses with API and GUI but I didn't find them, even with chatgpt I couldn't get any results.